# Using one Linux kernel for 2 devices with FIT image

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to use one embedded Linux kernel for 2 devices, I build this kernel with mkimage tool and rules in .dts file. Devices differs load and entry points. But u-boot doesn't use load and entry point addresses from configuration, only from kernel section. As result 2 big size data files (fully identical) are included into resulting .dtb file. It's inefficient. Can I transfer correct values from configuration to kernel sections? Or use links to single binary from both kernel sections?

Thank you in advance,
Dmytro Badekha.

Content of ITS file:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
description = "ARM FIT (Flattened Image Tree)";
#address-cells = <1>;

images {
    kernel@1 {
        description = "ARM OpenWrt Linux-3.14.77";
        data = /incbin/("./Image.gz");
        type = "kernel";
        arch = "arm";
        os = "linux";
        compression = "gzip";
        load = <0x42208000>;
        entry = <0x42208000>;
        hash@1 {
            algo = "crc32";
        };
        hash@2 {
            algo = "sha1";
        };
    };

    kernel@2 {
        description = "ARM OpenWrt Linux-3.14.77";
        data = /incbin/("./Image.gz");
        type = "kernel";
        arch = "arm";
        os = "linux";
        compression = "gzip";
        load = <0x80208000>;
        entry = <0x80208000>;
        hash@1 {
            algo = "crc32";
        };
        hash@2 {
            algo = "sha1";
        };
    };

    fdt@v3.0-ap160 {
        description = "ARM OpenWrt qcom-ipq806x-akxx device tree blob";
        data = /incbin/("./qcom-ipq8064-v3.0-ap160.dtb.gz");
        type = "flat_dt";
        arch = "arm";
        compression = "gzip";
        load = <0x43F00000>;
        hash@1 {
            algo = "crc32";
        };
        hash@2 {
            algo = "sha1";
        };
    };

    fdt@ap.dk04.1-c4 {
        description = "ARM OpenWrt qcom-ipq40xx-ap.dkxx device tree blob";
        data = /incbin/("./qcom-ipq40xx-ap.dk04.1-c4.dtb");
        type = "flat_dt";
        arch = "arm";
        compression = "none";
        hash@1 {
            algo = "crc32";
        };
        hash@2 {
            algo = "sha1";
        };
    };
};

configurations {
    default = "config@v3.0-ap160";

    config@v3.0-ap160 {
        description = "OpenWrt";
        kernel = "kernel@1";
        fdt = "fdt@v3.0-ap160";
    };

    config@ap.dk04.1-c4 {
        description = "OpenWrt";
        kernel = "kernel@2";
        fdt = "fdt@ap.dk04.1-c4";
    };

};
```

};